# Initialize a variable in the Webform template and refer it inside a repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, sitefinity

I am trying to assign an Eval value to a variable and trying to use that inside a repeater. Here's a brief example of what I am trying to do:

```
 <ItemTemplate>
  <% var test= Eval("year") %>
 <asp:Repeater DataSource='testlist'>
  <ItemTemplate>
  <a class="testclass" href='/testlink/<%= test%>/'>Test this</a>  
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
</ItemTemplate>
```

I end up getting this error

```
 CS0103: The name 'test' does not exist in the current context
```

I think my syntax is wrong. I tried looking for options for this online but most of them suggested a variable in the code behind. I am working with Sitefinity Webform templates, so would like to avoid code behind. Is there any way to do something on the aspx page itself instead of a code behind? 
One thing I forgot to mention is that the testlist does not have year property. The year property exists outside the repeater. And hence I want to assign it to a variable and use.

Comment: Use # in databinding context, not =

Comment: Maybe  is `<ItemTemplate>` is inside `Repeater`?

Comment: @Emanuele you are correct. there is also an Item template inside the repeater. I corrected it. Also, I tried # doesn't work.

Comment: You must use <%# inside Repeater because it's a databinding context. Try to replace tag with a Hyperlink runat="server". The code you edit is Classic Asp style, not Asp.Net

Answer (score 0):

Use like below

```
 <ItemTemplate>
 <asp:Repeater DataSource='testlist'>
  <a href='/testlink/<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "test") %>'>Test this</a>  
</asp:Repeater>
</ItemTemplate>
```